# Can't launch socket under another domain on the same server

Tags: apache, sockets

So far, I've got a funny problem. I had a socket running on my server for months, and I've came up with an idea of changing the host name.

After I did change the host name, and the links to the certificates, the socket no longer worked.

I own both domain names currently, let's say they are `example-old.com` and `example.com`, and I have certificates for both domains, issued by Cloudflare, both are wildcard ones (i.e., for `example.com` and `*.example.com`).

I didn't change the server, I didn't even restart it. When I change `example` back to `example_old`, both server name and certificate paths, everything works again. However, once I put the newer domain name here, nothing changes for it - `socket.example.com` just resolves as a 404 (as it would be even without virtual host declaration).

So, here's the code in `/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf` which declared my socket server.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName socket.example.com

        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html

        ProxyVia on
        RewriteEngine on

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html
        ServerName socket.example.com

        SSLEngine on
        SSLCertificateFile /var/www/subdomains/example/example.pem
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /var/www/subdomains/example/example.key
        SSLCertificateChainFile /var/www/subdomains/example/example.pem

        SSLProxyEngine On
        ProxyPreserveHost On
        ProxyRequests Off

        # This is for websocket requests
        ProxyPass /wss wss://localhost:9024/
        ProxyPassReverse /wss wss://localhost:9024/

        ProxyPass /wchat wss://localhost:9025/
        ProxyPassReverse /wchat wss://localhost:9025/

        ProxyPass / https://localhost:3333/
        ProxyPassReverse / https://localhost:3333/

</VirtualHost>
```

I don't really  remember if this change is the only one that has to be done in order for changing my socket server.

As a socket, I use Workerman for PHP. As neither the port, nor the server changed, I left my file `socket.php` untouched. When I launch the socket.php with the new domain names in  `/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf`, everything is silent, it doesn't respond neither to new connections, nor to anything else.

I also experimented with leaving running socket under the old domain name, declaring the same virtual host for the new domain name and trying to launch another instance of socket. The one, running on the old domain, works perfectly, while the new doesn't.

What could I do wrong? As far as I understand, there're must be something else that I must have done months ago when launching the original socket server. However, I don't remember what was it.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution finally, if anyone is wondering

Switched flexible to full encryption on Cloudflare and everything started working [image]